# Recursive PHP function is not returning the expected result

Tags: php, date, recursion

I am trying to create a recursive function which calculates gift delivery dates according to some predefined rules which are:

1. A gift can be delivered after one day of booking
2. If booked on Saturday or Sunday then the gift will be delivered after the next working day + one processing day.
3. The resulting date might not be in predefined holidays.

I have created the following function, but it’s returning me incorrect date.

```
// The delivery date might not be from these dates
$holidays_selected = array('23-10-2015', '24-10-2015', '28-10-2015');

echo $gift_delivery_date = getGiftDeliveryDate(date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+1 Day')), $holidays_selected);
// It prints 25-10-2015 what i expect is 27-10-2015

function getGiftDeliveryDate($asuumed_date, $holidays) {

    $tomorrow = '';
    if (in_array($asuumed_date, $holidays)) {
        $tomorrow = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($asuumed_date . '+1 Day'));
        getGiftDeliveryDate($tomorrow, $holidays);

    } else if (date('N', strtotime($asuumed_date)) == 6) {
        $tomorrow = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($asuumed_date . '+3 Day'));
        if(in_array($tomorrow, $holidays)) {
            $tomorrow = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($tomorrow . '+1 Day'));
            getGiftDeliveryDate($tomorrow, $holidays);
        }
    } else if (date('N', strtotime($asuumed_date)) == 7) {
        $tomorrow = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($asuumed_date . '+2 Day'));
        if(in_array($tomorrow, $holidays)) {
            $tomorrow = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($tomorrow . '+1 Day'));
            getGiftDeliveryDate($tomorrow, $holidays);
        }
    } else {
        $tomorrow = $asuumed_date;
    }

    return $tomorrow;
}
```

I expect `27-10-2015` as the output, but it is giving `25-10-2015` as the final output.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Also add expected and current output of date.

Comment: The question is a function not behaves as I expect so need a help to find out what is going wrong in a function.

Comment: I've mentioned expected result. Let me edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the return values from your function:

```
function getGiftDeliveryDate($asuumed_date, $holidays) {
    if (in_array($asuumed_date, $holidays)) {
        $tomorrow = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($asuumed_date . '+1 Day'));
        $tomorrow = getGiftDeliveryDate($tomorrow, $holidays);

    } else if (date('N', strtotime($asuumed_date)) == 6) {
        $tomorrow = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($asuumed_date . '+3 Day'));
        if (in_array($tomorrow, $holidays)) {
            $tomorrow = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($tomorrow . '+1 Day'));
            <b>$tomorrow =</b> getGiftDeliveryDate($tomorrow, $holidays);
        }
    } else if (date('N', strtotime($asuumed_date)) == 7) {
        $tomorrow = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($asuumed_date . '+2 Day'));
        if (in_array($tomorrow, $holidays)) {
            $tomorrow = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($tomorrow . '+1 Day'));
            <b>$tomorrow =</b> getGiftDeliveryDate($tomorrow, $holidays);
        }
    } else {
        $tomorrow = $asuumed_date;
    }

    return $tomorrow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is working fine. But i could not find out where you did changes. Can you please tell me where the problem was?

Comment: Oops got it. I was not assigning $tomorrow to `$tomorrow = getGiftDeliveryDate(*****)`. Feeling dumb :( Thanks for your help

Comment: `<b>$tomorrow =</b>` does not render (I presume it is for presentation here and is invalid PHP. It may have worked in the past, but not currently(?)—there was a meta post about this recently, but now I can't locate it (perhaps it was deleted)). Perhaps use some other way, like standard code comments?